# JQuery table sorter column resize not working with my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using [JQuery table sorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) with the widget/plug-in [column resize](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-resizable.html). For some reason, the resize functionality won't work with my table. If I copy and past the example code into JSFidle (with the dependancies specified) it works, but if I replace the HTML with my own table and adjust the javascript to target it, it does not work. What happens is that the "adjust" pointer symbol shows up, but I can't resize it.

This is my table in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxhW4/ (Does not work)

Here is a shorter version of my table. I striped away any extra rows, classes, and names: http://jsfiddle.net/KXUpY/ (Does not work)

This is the example in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4FMRh/2/ (Works) [I ACCIDENTALLY POSTED THE WRONG ONE BEFORE]

Here is a copy of my code for my table (I'm mostly posting it here because if I don't stackoverflow won't let me post any links.):

```
<table class="entry-table" id="2" style="width: auto">
    <thead>
        <tr class="entry-table-title">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">ID</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value">Title</td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value">Options</td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value">Files</td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value">Date&#39;s Are Cool!</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">300</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value">Num 1, Num 2, Num 3</td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value">TEST</td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">302</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value">Get</td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">303</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value">Test</td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">304</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">305</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">306</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">307</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">308</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="entry-table-cell">
            <td name="ID" class="entry-table-value">309</td>
            <td name="3" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="6" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="7" class="entry-table-value"></td>
            <td name="8" class="entry-table-value"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Why won't it work for my table? I really have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the issue. The tablesort library was expecting `th` tags when I accidentally used `td` tags in the header.